# How do I call helm in the middle of switch-to-buffer (using vertico)?

Tags: helm, minibuffer, vertico

Say I'm in the middle of `switch-to-buffer` (using vertico.el btw), I couldn't find the buffer/file I need. I want to use a key binding to call `helm-recentf` or `helm-locate` etc, how should I go about doing that?  tried

```
(use-package vertico
  :bind (:map vertico-map
              ("M-t" . (lambda()(interactive)(vertico-exit)(helm-recentf)))))
```

but that doesn't work, the code after (vertico-exit) doesn't get called. If I remove (vertico-exit), vertico will hang around.  what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: A [recursive edit](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. `emacs -Q`
2. When in `*scratch*` buffer, copy the below snippet

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
 '(minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode t))

(package-initialize)

(vertico-mode 1)
(require 'helm)

(defvar-local my-vertico-command nil)

(advice-add 'vertico--exhibit
            :after
            (defun vertico--setup:after ()
              (when (and
                     ;; The command is `switch-to-buffer'
                     (eq my-vertico-command 'switch-to-buffer)
                     ;; There are no matching candidates
                     (null vertico--candidates))
                ;; Put current minibuffer contents in kill ring.
                ;; It can be yanked if needed as a pattern for
                ;; `helm-recentf'.
                (kill-new (minibuffer-contents))
                ;; Launch `helm-recentf' on exit
                (run-with-timer nil nil 'helm-recentf)
                ;; Exit the current command which `switch-to-buffer'.
                (call-interactively 'exit-minibuffer))))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
          (defun my-minibuffer-with-setup-hook ()
            ;; Note down the command which is reading from minibuffer
            ;; in `my-vertico-command'.
            (setq my-vertico-command this-command)))
```

3. `M-x eval-buffer RET`
4. `C-x b`, start typing some gibberish.  You will start with `vertico`, but will end up with `helm`.

---